# Java receives the audio data from multiple sources on the same port, how to separate and play

Tags: java, port, multicast

I am developing a LAN multi-person voice real-time intercom Android project. There is no server. I use multicast to send data, but when two people talk at the same time, the data received by the third person is mixed and disorganized. I tried to separate the data using IP and play it separately, but it still works badly. What is the solution, thank you!

Comment: maybe as you send data, you could  add a source identifier to the sent packets

Comment: Packets can be distinguished by IP. In fact, I have separated according to IP, but the sound is very messy.